# How to get line numbers of the snippets matching a regexp?

Tags: python, regex

How is it possible to obtain the **line numbers** of all the text snippets matching a given `regexp`, within a file?

```
file_content = f.read()

m = re.compile('regexp')
# How to extract line numbers of the matched text snippets?
```

The regular expression cannot span lines.

Comment: egrep -n REGEX FILE|cut -f1 -d:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 with open(somefile, 'r') as f:
     line_numbers = [n for n, line in enumerate(f) if re.search(someRegexp, line)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
reg="ha*"
count=0
f = open(somefile,'r')
while True:
        line= f.readline()
        if not line: break
        else:
                count+=1
                if re.search(reg,line):
                        print count,line
```